# how add DataSource & DataSet in Angular Code with ActiveReportJS

Tags: angular, activereports

i wanna create a report with ActiveReportJS Angular. 
how i add DataSource and DataSet to it???

this is not working. this code has a following error:
[image: 1]

`cannot read property 'map' of undefined.`

Comment: Please show us some more code and tell us what you tried so far. There is no hint where 'map' is defined. Also don't use an URL to an image please, because it could be invalid some day. Paste the source here and/or create a https://plnkr.co/ that shows the problem.

Comment: i have error in this file: ar-js-viewer.js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DataProvider: jsondata`, you need to set it to `DataProvider: "JSON"`.

Please refer to the [Blood Test sample report](https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/demos/) to see an example of how the data source and dataset are configured in the report.

For additional information about data binding, refer to our documentation [here.](https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/DeveloperGuide/ActiveReportsJSDesigner/Databinding#databinding)

Best,

GrapeCity Support Team

https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact

Answer (score 0):

thank you to respond.
my problem still not solved. I want to [Update data source at run time](https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/DeveloperGuide/ActiveReportsJSViewer/Features). I follow this page but I don't understand it and it not work.

when I add (& Parameters!Data.Value) in the last of jsondata="", I can't add a dataset to it.

```
jsondata=""& Parameters!Data.Value    ----> fail
```